# disable framework7 animations

Tags: jquery, html-framework-7

I am using framework7 and it is one hell of a library but bad at animation. It works in some OS version, it is sluggish in some. Now I just want to disable the animations all together for the function is all I am after.

During ini, I have the following:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    modalTitle: 'MeLife',
    // Enable Material theme
    material: true,
    animatePages:false,
    externalLinks:'.external',
    sortable:false,
    swipeout:false,
    materialRippleElements:'',
});
```

The `animatePages` seem to have the correct effect but only on page transitions. I want to disable the animations on click of buttons/links which I believe should have been achieved by setting `materialRippleElements` to empty but nothing yet.

Any any ideas please?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting the **parameter** materialRipple to false?

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    modalTitle: 'MeLife',
    // Enable Material theme
    material: true,
    animatePages:false,
    externalLinks:'.external',
    sortable:false,
    swipeout:false,
    materialRipple:false
});
```